# Using PHP to post an image to Cheezburger, json_decode won't handle the response

Tags: php, curl, json

I am trying to post an image to Cheezburger.com with a PHP script, and return the URL to the user. The post part works fine, I get the links, IDs etc. back in JSON format, but when I run `json_decode($var, true)` it only gives me the raw JSON back. Here is the string that got fed into the script:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 6980805120,
            "link": "https://api.cheezburger.com/v1/assets/6980805120",
            "created_time": 1358451002,
            "updated_time": 1358451002,
            "media": [
                {
                    "name": "maxW580",
                    "url": "https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW580/6980805120/h89D91707/",
                    "height": 500,
                    "width": 500,
                    "is_animated": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "maxW320",
                    "url": "https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW320/6980805120/h89D91707/",
                    "height": 320,
                    "width": 320,
                    "is_animated": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "square50",
                    "url": "https://i.chzbgr.com/square50/6980805120/h89D91707/",
                    "height": 50,
                    "width": 50,
                    "is_animated": false
                }
            ],
            "title": "JSA, UR WEBSIET IZ AWSUM. URE HIRD!",
            "description": "JSA, UR WEBSIET IZ AWSUM. URE HIRD! -- This image was created by jsa005 from JSiVi using the JSiVi Meme Generator. Try it out at http://jsivi.uni.me!",
            "asset_type_id": 0,
            "share_url": "http://chzb.gr/10Cg1PS"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run `json_decode($jsonstring, true)` on that, `$jsonstring` being the variable returned by cURL containing the string above, I only get back the string I fed in. I am confused.

```
$fields = array(
'access_token' => $this->getToken(),
'title' => $title,
'description' => $description,
'content' => $base64data,
'anonymous' => 'true');
$url = 'https://api.cheezburger.com/v1/assets';
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$jsonstring = json_decode($result, TRUE);
```

Comment: `it only gives me the raw JSON back` What makes you say that? How are you examining it?

Comment: Running the string as you gave it through json_decode returned a reasonable result using php 5.4. All I can recommend is that you double-extra-check that the value of $result exactly matches the string you provided as an example.

Comment: Yep. A standard case of not narrowing down the problem enough by isolating CURL then `json_decode`.

Comment: I used print_r on the variable.

Comment: As a thank you to the helpful Stack Overflow community, here's the site I'm using it on (you have to login to save to Cheezburger as it also adds to my DB): http://jsivi.uni.me/meme/gen_index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

before running `curl_exec($ch);` Without it, response is printed directly into your browser, so you are seeing "raw" JSON and `$response` is boolean value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`). [See manual page for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

Comment: Would you like to explain why?

Comment: "*There will be times when you need to get the response from curl_exec and capture the transfer - this is not very well documented but you can do so with the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER Option*" [from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#109653).

Comment: Thank you, this has sorted the problem. ;)