# php json decode curl_exec result of shared link on facebook

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, curl

I use curl php to share link on facebook all is fine and I'VE got this result 
`{ "id": "the_link_id" }`. I tried to got the id with:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
$post_id = $json->{'id'};
echo $post_id;
```

but I got this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object ...

Comment: Why don't you print out the result and show us what's inside? var_dump($result);

Comment: What does var_dump($json) give you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP to post an image to Cheezburger, json\_decode won't handle the response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386981/using-php-to-post-an-image-to-cheezburger-json-decode-wont-handle-the-response)

Comment: boolean true => boolean true

var_dump($json)  = > int 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i just added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);